# How to download/apply all patches from gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Can you explain how to work with the same change_id in gerrit simultaneously, let's say me and someone else? We are doing all the things the same way:

```
git review -d change_id;
git add -A;
git commit --amend;
git review branch_name; // push changes to the same branch and change_id
```

For example, when I create patchset "1" and "3" and someone else patch "2" then I want to fetch "2" and still have "1" and "3" on my local. How to do this? Because when I download a change by:

```
git review -d change_id;
```

I can see only my changes "1" and "3" but not "2".
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 2nd patchset does exist, you can specify its ordinal number after the change_id,

```
git review -d change_id,2
```

As `git review` is a third-party command line tool, it may be unavailable. We can also use `git fetch` to get the patchset. Every patchset is associated with an internal ref like `refs/changes/bb/aaabb/n`, where `aaabb` is the change number or change id, `bb` is the result of `aaabb mod 100`, and `n` is the ordinal number of the patchset.

```
# Suppose the ref is refs/changes/22/62522/2
git fetch origin refs/changes/22/62522/2
git checkout FETCH_HEAD

# We can also create a local branch, for example 62522_2, at the same time
git fetch origin refs/changes/22/62522/2:refs/heads/62522_2
git checkout 62522_2
```

Comment: this command does not work:
`
git review -d change_id,2
`
it fetches only changeset "2" and removes my changes

Comment: Ok, after calling:
git fetch origin refs/changes/22/62522/2
git checkout FETCH_HEAD

should I call:
git pull?

Comment: @Garik I tried `git review -d 6993543`, and it fetched and created a local branch `review/unknown/6993543`. Then with `git review -d 6993543,1`, it created `review/unknown/6993543-patch1`. With `git review -d 6993543,2`, it created `review/unknown/6993543-patch2`. What do you mean by `removes my changes`? `git review -d` would create a local branch and check it out.

Comment: @Garik `git pull` is not necessary in the case of `git fetch && git checkout`.

Comment: What @ElpieKay says is correct. Thank you for your explanation. Just skip my "removes my changes" and everything works, the problem was that someone push changes and override previous changes, that is why latest patchset was looking like it removes previous patch